# NullPointerException while opening new frame

Tags: java, swing

today I'm having a bit of a slight, see, I'm trying to run my code and I'm getting a NullPointerException. The clues in the exception leads me to this function right here:

```
private void irGuiJuego(JFrame frame){
    SwingConsole.run(new GUIJuego(), 800, 600, true);
    frame.dispose();
}
```

Where SwingConsole would have this code:

```
package utiles;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SwingConsole {

    public static void run(final JFrame frame, final int width, final int height, final boolean exitOnClose) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (exitOnClose)
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                frame.setSize(width, height);
                //frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    public static void run(final JFrame frame, final int width, final int height, final boolean exitOnClose, final String title) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (exitOnClose)
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                frame.setTitle(title);
                frame.setSize(width, height);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }


}
```

It is kind of odd, considering that I'm using the same method to open up another frame, in this function to be specific:

```
private void volverMenuInicio(JFrame frame){
    SwingConsole.run(new MenuInicio(), 300, 150, true);
    frame.dispose();
}
```

I'll leave you guys a pastebin of the GUIJuego Frame, since it's sort of excessive to post it here: http://pastebin.com/LSXbc7KE , have the pastebin of the other frame too, in case you need it: http://pastebin.com/hbdd7j84

Edit: Here's the stacktrace, sorry for the lack of it before!

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)    at
>   gui.GUIJuego.(GUIJuego.java:113)    at
>   gui.MenuNuevoJuego.irGuiJuego(MenuNuevoJuego.java:95)     at
>   gui.MenuNuevoJuego.access$2(MenuNuevoJuego.java:94)   at
>   gui.MenuNuevoJuego$2.actionPerformed(MenuNuevoJuego.java:74)  at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Thanks for reading, by the way!

Comment: Please provide the stack trace, that's the key piece of data for investigating an NPE.

Comment: What's the stack trace of the exception? It tells precisely where the exception happens. Without this information, we can only guess, or transform ourselves into a human JVM.

Comment: Must be a law of nature.  If it's tag `Java`, and the title contains `NullPointerException`, you can bet there won't be a stacktrace in the body.  Probably because once you've actually looked at the stacktrace, the solution is typically pretty simple...

Comment: I would suspect that frame may be null

Comment: Just edited in the stacktrace, also, how can the frame be null if I'm creating it right there?

Comment: The problem happens in GUIJuego.java, at line 113. Without seeing the code of this class and knowing which is the line 113, we can't answer. Learn to read the stack trace, and to use a debugger to execute the code line by line, and inspect the value of variables.

Comment: You were right, that's where the issue was, I spotted it right before you posted it. I might as well learn to read the stacktrace if I can cease to struggle understanding the lack of source, oh, I've used the debugger too, but I ened to learn more about it. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NPE is being thrown from line 113 in GUIJuego.java, as the stack trace indicates:

```
panelDatosCiudad.add(arcaLabel);
```

It's happening because `arcaLabel`, defined in line 35, is never set to a value, and so you're adding a null JLabel to the container.

Comment: Actually, reading up through the comments, seems like JB Nizet did most of the prompting for information that led to my answer. If JB wishes to post in answer form I'd be happy to withdraw mine and have you accept his.

Comment: That's very noble of you, is there a way to contact him and tell him that if he would like to post his answer that I'd accept it right away?